How to compile C++ program for older version of MacOS?
here are my build steps:
conan install . --build=missing
cmake --preset conan-default
cmake --build --preset conan-release

this results in a binary that is compatible with only the current (last) version of MacOS
otool -l mybin
platform 1
    minos 14.5
      sdk 14.5

How to change this builds steps to compile for MacOS 10.14?

set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.14).

This question got a response in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/16473

I was able to build my program for MacOS 10.15 by adding os.version=10.15 to a conan2 profile located in ~/.conan2/profiles.
here is what the new binary output:
 platform 1
    minos 10.15
      sdk 14.5

